# select option is not updating the view if update the model from angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html Code Is

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="schedule.nthSelectThe" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <option ng-selected="true">first</option>
    <option>second</option>
    <option>third</option>
    <option>fourth</option>
    <option>last</option>
</select>
```

Angular Code

```
var freq_relative_intervalRevers ={
    '1':'first',
    '2':'second',
    '4':'third',
    '8':'fourth',
    '16':'last'
 };
 $scope.$applyAsync(function () {                                  
   $scope.schedule.nthSelectThe = freq_relative_intervalRevers[editRecord.freq_relative_interval.toString()];                                    
 });
```

The update is not reflecting 
even i tried without $applyAsunc like

```
$scope.schedule.nthSelectThe = freq_relative_intervalRevers[editRecord.freq_relative_interval.toString()];
```

I checked variable `$scope.schedule.nthDayThe`
even in `console.log()` value is expected but in view part is showing first as selected.

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: `schedule.nthSelectThe` !== `schedule.nthDayThe`

Comment: You are using 2 different variables, How it suppose to work

Comment: sorry its mistake actually i have to select option see the actual code is this one         $scope.schedule.nthSelectThe = freq_relative_intervalRevers[editRecord.freq_relative_interval.toString()];                                    but its not working please help me out.

Comment: Use `$timeout` like `$timeout(function () {                                  
   $scope.schedule.nthSelectThe = freq_relative_intervalRevers[editRecord.freq_relative_interval.toString()];                                    
 }, 0);`